# I'm struggling to get jQuery loops to communicate with HTML5 download functionality

Tags: javascript

I'm using TamperMonkey to create this - thus I already have jQuery in the header, but basically I'm trying to download all the kitten images from [this page](https://www.buzzfeed.com/chelseamarshall/best-kitten-pictures?utm_term=.avy4nRbyd8#.ay9X2BNmY8) using the Download Album button.

This is just a silly replica of the project I'm actually working on, but the same principles apply on both and if I can fix this, I can fix that.

I concatenated a link with the necessary data onto the title of the article, thus I have an ID and a target.

The errors I'm getting are strange, the console log fills up with errors I don't recognise or know how to fix, and then the website changes to match the source of the first image, and I have to press the back button to go back to the Buzzfeed page.

This is my code so far:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var title = $('#mod-buzz-header-1 > hgroup > h1').text();
    var currentLink = "";
    var imgTotal = 100;
    var i = 0;

    $('#mod-buzz-header-1 > hgroup > h1').html(title + " || <a id='download_button' href='#' >Download Album</a>");

    $("#download_button").on('click', function() {

        for (i = 0; i < imgTotal; i++) {

            currentLink = $('article img:eq(' + i + ')').attr('src');

            $('#download_button').attr('href', currentLink);

            $('#download_button').click();


        }

    });

})();
```

So I was wondering if somebody could tell me how wrong my code is and a possible fix.

Thanks guys!

Comment: well what are the errors?

Comment: So why are you causing an infinite loop?

Comment: The code calls `.click()` within `.click()` handler

Comment: The errors don't fit into one page, if I could record and copy the log to the clipboard I might be able to paste them but I can't. They immediately disappear. Also, how come .click() causes an infinite loop? I thought it'd just click 100 times (each time altering the Href and downloading a different file).